# How can I convert a string containing the binary data pattern into bytes using java?

Tags: string, utf-8, binary

I have to consume a web-service which is expecting a PDF file(base64binary data) as string. As the communication is done in XML UTF-8 encoding the string has many invalid elements, It is throwing a error. I tried with keeping the string CDATA but still its not working. Any idea how to overcome this situation?

I tried to write the binary data to string by formatting i.e 0x530x770x610x720x6F0x6F0x70 now how to get it back to bytes? can i read this pattern into bytes?

I am unsing Websphere process server and Websphere Integration Developer. We downloaded the chunck from a webservice and now need to send the base64binary as string to other service which we are struck. please help urget

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're misunderstanding what you're supposed to do - you can't write binary data into a text stream (since, as you figured out already, not every binary sequence will consist of valid characters). This is why [your spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/PER-xmlschema-2-20040318/#base64Binary) says *base64binary*, not *raw binary*. Let me quote:

> Definition:
>
> base64Binary represents Base64-encoded arbitrary binary
> data. The ·value space· of base64Binary is the set of finite-length
> sequences of binary octets. For base64Binary data the entire binary
> stream is encoded using the Base64 Alphabet in [RFC 2045].
>
> The lexical forms of base64Binary values are limited to the 65
> characters of the Base64 Alphabet defined in [RFC 2045], i.e., a-z,
> A-Z, 0-9, the plus sign (+), the forward slash (/) and the equal sign
> (=), together with the characters defined in [XML 1.0 (Second
> Edition)] as white space. No other characters are allowed.

You're not telling us what system you're using, so I can't tell you precisely how to encode your data, but you'll find pre-existing implementations of base64 for pretty much every language.